# VBA Excel 2010 - For Loop Delete Row if Next Record is different from previous record based on column values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a list of rows, that have several columns, and what I wish to do is, remove the rows that don't match a criteria based on the value of the previous rows. 
Basicly i have a column with a bunch of ID's that repeat themselfs, and another column with a date.

I've sorted the records ascending by those two columns

```
   Public Sub sbOrderRecords()

    Application.Sheets("sheet1").Select

    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Range("A1"), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending
        ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Range("E1"), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Header = xlYes
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

So my goal is to delete the records where the ID is equal to the previous record but the date is older, leaving only one record by ID with the Newest date.

```
Public Sub sbDeleteByIMAndDate()

Dim currentIM As String
Dim MaxDateCurrentIM As Date

Dim dateRange As Range
Dim imRange As Range

With Sheets("sheet1")
        Set imRange = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


For IM = 1 To imRange.Rows.Count

    currentIM = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(IM, 1).value
    currentDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(IM, 5).value

    For J = Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 1 To 2 Step -1
        If currentIM = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(J, 1).Value And currentDate > (Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(J, 5).Value)  Then
            Rows(J).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next J

Next IM

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This seems to work but it's very slow, and only has around 6000 records.

Any suggestion would by highly appreciated

Comment: What I am missing here? You can sort the ID column in Ascending order and Date column in Descending order and then delete the rows within the loop if Current Row ID is equal to the Previous Row ID. Isn't it?

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry I forgot to add a sentence, it's works but is very very slow. Any ideas in how to improve the performance? I understand your logic, but can't seem to know how to apply it, it's possible for a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, give this a try and tweak it accordingly if required.

```
Sub DuplicateRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
Dim Rng As Range

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
lr = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Assuming Column A is ID column and column E is Date column
ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=Range("E2"), order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

For i = lr To 2 Step -1
    'Comparing ID column A
    If ws.Cells(i, 1) = ws.Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
        If Rng Is Nothing Then
            Set Rng = ws.Cells(i, 1)
        Else
            Set Rng = Union(Rng, ws.Cells(i, 1))
        End If
    End If
Next i

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    Rng.EntireRow.Delete
End If
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: sktneer, thank you very much it worked like a charm. If I may ask you just one more question, I understand all the code expect Union(Rng, ws.Cells(i, 1)) if you could provide a quick explanation it would be great. thank you again for your support.

Comment: @NelsonFerro You're welcome! Glad it worked. The Union method is used to get all the cells which meet the criteria into one range variable and delete the rows at once in the end instead of deleting each found row within the loop. That makes the code faster. As far as Union method is concerned, when you loop the rows and find the first cell which meets the criteria, the Rng variable doesn't contain any cell reference in it so you just set the Rng variable equal to the cell found e.g. say the first cell found was A100, the address of Rng variable will be A100......

Comment: ......But next time, when you find another cell which meets the criteria, say A99 this time, the union method will set the Rng variable to hold both the cells A100 and A99 i.e. A100,A99 and so on... And in the end, you may delete the rows of Rng variable. Sorry if my explanation was bad, that's not my field. Lol

Comment: II understand now, great explanation, thank you @sktneer.

Comment: @NelsonFerro You're welcome! Glad you found it helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Fastest would probably be to go record a macro and run remove duplicates.  Take that and modify it out to meet your needs.

NOTE:  Remove duplicates will keep the entry it finds first and delete the rest faster than anything I have ever written.  Good for you you are sorting already.

1) Change the E column sort to xlDecsending so your newest fall above your oldest.

2) Select all the cells and click Remove Duplicates in the Data Tab.

3) Un-select all and select only column A.

I think this should do what you want.

Efficiency:  You are hitting the sheet to hard. All those checks directly to cells and modifications to those cells are killing you.  Research the variant array.

```
Dim arr() as variant
arr = sheets("WHATEVER").range("A1:B100").value
```

That is easy and fast.  Now your data is in RAM not excel.  A variant array assigned like this will start at row 1, column 1 for the first element. `arr(1, 1)` is cell A1 and `arr(1, 2)` is B1.

```
For IM = 1 To 1000
    currentIM = arr(IM, 1).value
    currentDate = arr(IM,5).value
```

when you want to delete a row in your comparison you can `arr(1,1) = "": arr(1,2) = ""` when you are finished you can read the data back into the worksheet.

```
Range("A1:B100") = arr
```

You would need to sort after but this would be faster than your code and slower than remove duplicates.